# Is this able to be done?

Tags: stages-of-the-path, mantra

Can you say a mantra for only people with good intentions? I said the green Tara mantra for all the sentient beings with good intentions. Is that ok, because that mantra helps you release hope for a particular outcome and bring the energy back to yourself, generating inner peace and clarity